# Fatal error: Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first statement in the script

Tags: php, namespace

Не могу понять почему выскакивает данная ошибка. Вот код файла, в котором ошибка  Fatal error: Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first statement in the script in /var/www/html/phpinstagram/phpinstagram/Instagram.php on line 2

```
<?
namespace phpinstagram;

class Instagram {

/*
 * @var array
 */
protected $_commands = array();

/*
 * @var \phpinstagram\Instagram\Client\Communication
 */
protected $_communication;

/*
 * @var \phpinstagram\Instagram\Api\Feed
 */
public $feed;

/*
 * @var \phpinstagram\Instagram\Api\Auth
 */
public $auth;

public function __construct() {
    $this->feed = new \phpinstagram\Instagram\Api\Feed();
    $this->feed->setInstagram($this);
    $this->auth = new \phpinstagram\Instagram\Api\Auth();
    $this->auth->setInstagram($this);
    $this->_communication = new \phpinstagram\Instagram\Client\Communication();
}

public function addCommand(\phpinstagram\Instagram\Command\ICommand $cmd) {
    $this->_commands[] = $cmd;
}

public function run() {
    $executed = array();
    //$cookieJar = null;
    foreach ($this->_commands as $utcmd) {
        if ($utcmd instanceof \phpinstagram\Instagram\Command\ICommand) {
            /*
             * @var \phpinstagram\Instagram\Command\ICommand
             */
            $cmd = $utcmd;

            //if (!is_null($cookieJar))
            //  $this->_communication->getClient()->setCookieJar($cookieJar);

            foreach ($cmd->dependsOn() as $dependency) {
                foreach ($executed as $previous) {
                    if (get_class($previous) == '\Instagram\Command\\' . $dependency) {
                        break 2;
                    }
                }
                throw new \phpinstagram\Instagram\Command\DependencyException(
                    'Command ' . get_class($cmd) . " depends on $dependency but it never was executed!\n\n"
                );
            }
            $cmd->setCommunication($this->_communication);

            $cmd->validate();

            //echo get_class($cmd)." is valid. executing...\n\n";
            $cmd->exec();

            $executed[] = $cmd;

            // reset parameters
            $this->_communication->getClient()->resetParameters();
            //$cookieJar = $this->_communication->getClient()->getCookieJar();
        }
    }

    // reset commands
    $this->_commands = array();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Решено, ответ можно посмотреть тут: [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34184030/fatal-error-namespace-declaration-statement-has-to-be-the-very-first-statement)

Comment: Об этом написано в первом комментарии к Определению пространства имен http://php.net/manual/ru/language.namespaces.definition.php#115504